# For migration large scale record file which is faster Excel or CSV with respect of PHP?

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

For migration large scale record file which is faster Excel or CSV with respect of PHP ?

Comment: CSV by far and away: you can write to csv directly from PHP without the need for external libraries like PHPExcel, and CSV has the added bonus of not being limited to 1 million rows.... use Excel if you need colours and merged cells and formulae, but CSV for a simple data export

Comment: Thanks Mark for your quick response !

Answer (score 1):

csv is a very simple file format and as such needs much less processing to work through it.  And as Mark Baker pointed out, csv does not have any size limitations.